# Longest Absolute File Path in Leetcode

Tags: c#, performance, programming-challenge

I solved the [Longest Absolute File Path](https://leetcode.com/problems/longest-absolute-file-path/) challenge from Leetcode.

The question is

> Suppose we abstract our file system by a string in the following
>   manner:
>
> The string `"dir\n\tsubdir1\n\tsubdir2\n\t\tfile.ext"` represents:
>
> ```
>  dir
>      subdir1
>      subdir2
>          file.ext
> ```
>
> The directory dir contains an empty sub-directory subdir1 and a sub-directory subdir2 containing a file file.ext.
>
> The string
>   `"dir\n\tsubdir1\n\t\tfile1.ext\n\t\tsubsubdir1\n\tsubdir2\n\t\tsubsubdir2\n\t\t\tfile2.ext"`
>   represents:
>
> ```
> dir
>      subdir1
>          file1.ext
>          subsubdir1
>      subdir2
>          subsubdir2
>              file2.ext
> ```
>
> The directory dir contains two sub-directories subdir1 and subdir2. subdir1 contains a file file1.ext and an empty
>   second-level sub-directory subsubdir1. subdir2 contains a second-level
>   sub-directory subsubdir2 containing a file file2.ext.
>
> We are interested in finding the longest (number of characters)
>   absolute path to a file within our file system. For example, in the
>   second example above, the longest absolute path is
>   `"dir/subdir2/subsubdir2/file2.ext"`, and its length is 32 (not
>   including the double quotes).
>
> Given a string representing the file system in the above format,
>   return the length of the longest absolute path to file in the
>   abstracted file system. If there is no file in the system, return 0.
>
> Note: The name of a file contains at least a . and an extension. The
>   name of a directory or sub-directory will not contain a .. Time
>   complexity required: O(n) where n is the size of the input string.
>
> Notice that `a/aa/aaa/file1.txt` is not the longest file path, if there
>   is another path `aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa/sth.png`.

The approach used is very similar to the way one would do this by hand. This solution looks like it has a lot of if/else statements.

Could you please suggest a cleaner way to write this solution.

```
public static int LengthLongestPath(string input) {
  var prefixLength = new Dictionary < int,int > ();
  int countT = 0, lengthSoFar = 0, maxLength = 0;
  bool isFile = false;
  for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++) {
   if (input[i] == '\n') {
    if (prefixLength.ContainsKey(countT - 1)) {
     prefixLength[countT] = lengthSoFar + prefixLength[countT - 1] + 1;
    } else {
     prefixLength[countT] = lengthSoFar;
    }

    if (isFile == true) {
     maxLength = Math.Max(maxLength, prefixLength[countT]);
     isFile = false;
    }
    lengthSoFar = 0;
    ++i;
    countT = 0;
    while (input[i] == '\t') {
     ++countT;
     ++i;
    }
    --i;
   } else {
    ++lengthSoFar;
    if (input[i] == '.') {
     isFile = true;
    }
   }
  }
  // To handle cases where file occours in the end of the string.
  if (isFile == true) {
   if (prefixLength.ContainsKey(countT - 1)) {
    maxLength = Math.Max(maxLength, prefixLength[countT - 1] + lengthSoFar + 1);
   } else {
    maxLength = Math.Max(maxLength, lengthSoFar);
   }
   isFile = false;
  }
  return maxLength;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, it is a little bit late to answer this question but I will do it nevertheless, because it's winterbash!

I had a hard time to read your code because of the level of indentation. I would suggest using the default of 4 spaces instead of 1 space.

Another problem with the code had been at first glance the `countT` variable but just because of the name. Abbreviations makes the code so much harder to read and understand. If the variable would have been named `countedTabs` its purpose would have been cristal clear.

One should use `var` if the type is easy to see by the right hand side of the assignment.

Manipulating a loop variable (`i`) if one can avoid is a bad habit and can lead to hard to find bugs. A simple `else if (input[i] == '\t') { ++countedTabs; }` would have been the way to avoid this.

If one need to know if a key exists in a `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` `ContainsKey()` is the way to go, but only if the possible value isn't needed. If one needs the value one should use `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>.TryGetValue(TKey, out TValue)` because accessing the value later by calling `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>[TKey]` will internal call the `ContainsKey()` as well.

Instead of doing `if (booleanVariable == true)` one should use `if (booleanVariable)`. One doesn't need to compare a boolean to `true` because the result of the comparison is just a boolean value as well. That beeing said, you can safely remove the `isFile = false;` at the end of that `if` block because it won't be used anymore. A last word about this `if`: The comment you placed above the `if` is a good comment because it describes why you have the `if` in place.

One last point to make, don't declare multiple variables in one line. This just hurts the readability of the code.

Summing up leads to

```
public static int LengthLongestPath(string input)
{

    var prefixLength = new Dictionary<int, int>();
    var countedTabs = 0;
    var lengthSoFar = 0;
    var maxLength = 0;
    var isFile = false;

    for (var i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
    {
        if (input[i] == '\n')
        {
            if (prefixLength.TryGetValue(countedTabs - 1, out int value))
            {
                prefixLength[countedTabs] = lengthSoFar + value + 1;
            }
            else
            {
                prefixLength[countedTabs] = lengthSoFar;
            }

            if (isFile == true)
            {
                maxLength = Math.Max(maxLength, prefixLength[countedTabs]);
                isFile = false;
            }
            lengthSoFar = 0;
            countedTabs = 0;

        }
        else if (input[i] == '\t')
        {
            ++countedTabs;
        }
        else
        {
            ++lengthSoFar;
            if (input[i] == '.')
            {
                isFile = true;
            }
        }
    }
    // To handle cases where file occours in the end of the string.
    if (isFile)
    {
        if (prefixLength.TryGetValue(countedTabs - 1, out int value))
        {
            maxLength = Math.Max(maxLength, value + lengthSoFar + 1);
        }
        else
        {
            maxLength = Math.Max(maxLength, lengthSoFar);
        }
    }
    return maxLength;
}
```